# How to use function parameters if function have @Test annotation?

Tags: java, testng

Is there any way to use parameters in a function if the function has `@test` annotation. I have a function like below:

```
@Test(@Test(priority=1, alwaysRun =true))
public void Home_page_Flextronics(String sUserName, String sPassword) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        CommonFunctions.LaunchApplication();            
        CommonFunctions.Login(sUserName, sPassword);    
        CommonFunctions.ClickOnModule("Customers"); 
        CommonFunctions.ClickOnHome();
        CommonFunctions.Logout();       
    }
```

However when I am trying to run above code its giving me error:

> Method Home_page_Flextronics requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied
>   in the @Test annotation.

If I remove the parameters and use hardcoded values, its working fine and it is requirement of my framework. I have gone through other solutions mostly suggest to use `@Parameter` annotation or data provider. But I don't want to use that as I want to take testdata from excel sheet. Please let me know if there is any other way present to handle this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: ***Wait.*** You want your test data to come from an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: @Makoto be happy he didn't say Access ;-)

Comment: Yes I want the data from the excel sheet.

Comment: @TomJonckheere:  at least an Access database could be talked about, even if it were in sharp whispers behind one's back.  I've never seen a request for test data to come from an Excel spreadsheet before; the likely reason being that you'd have to test that your test is pulling in the Excel data correctly.

Comment: Guys it's fine if you don't know.I already mentioned in my question that I don't want to use @parameters or dataprovider and push the data using xml. I know the other ways. I asked this because its my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Junit Theories [(introduction)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/introduction-to-junit-theories.html)

```
import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoints;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class AdditionWithTheoriesTest {

  @DataPoints
  public static int[] positiveIntegers() {
       return new int[]{
                        1, 10, 1234567};
  }

  @Theory
  public void a_plus_b_is_greater_than_a_and_greater_than_b(Integer a, Integer b) {
      assertTrue(a + b > a);
      assertTrue(a + b > b);
  }
}
```

This way you can pass parameters to a test. In your method annotated with DataPoints you'll need to fetch all the excell data and return it.